# Luks and encryption key

Tags: ext4, luks

I want to check how safe is this solution, I can't find on the web what I have and the differences in scenarios I found make me uneasy especially we are talking about security.

What I have is one hard drive with 3 partitions, 2 with ext4 and one swap. 
/ - ext4
swap
/home - encrypted with Luks - formatted with ext4

I have encryption key stored on my root partition in /root folder, but I am feeling this is not very safe.
Is that safe? the root partition is not encrypted so it feels unsafe.

if you could advise it would be fab :)

Comment: When you ask safe, you need to add "safe against...". Anything can be safe against X but unsafe against Y. For encrypted partitions, normally the password (to decrypt the key and then decrypt the partition) is asked at boot, which is not a problem for an end-user computer, but a problem for a server. If it is instead hardcoded in some files on the same disk, then access to the disk means access to everything, including what is encrypted. There are other solutions for a server.

Answer (score 2):

Encryption protects your system from offline access, i.e. access to your hardware.

If someone can access your hard drive, mount your root partition and recover the encryption keys, nothing is stopping them from decrypting your other partitions and mounting them as well.